# How to set headers and footers in a new document with google-docs-api and Java

Tags: java, google-docs-api

I need to reproduce a word document using google-docs-api but I don't know how to insert headers and footers in the new document. It seems that there's no request for that.
 Any suggestions?

Comment: I implemented inserting header to a new doc today using [google-docs-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-docs/v1-rev20191017-1.30.3). Note that, this a latest version released on Oct 25,2019

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you can use the method [`documents.create`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create) to create a blank document using the title given in the request.

**HTTP request**

```
POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents
```

**Request body**

```
{
  "documentId": string,
  "title": string,
  "body": {
    object(Body)
  },
  "headers": {
    string: {
      object(Header)
    },
    ...
  },
  "footers": {
    string: {
      object(Footer)
    },
    ...
  },
  "footnotes": {
    string: {
      object(Footnote)
    },
    ...
  },
  "documentStyle": {
    object(DocumentStyle)
  },
  "suggestedDocumentStyleChanges": {
    string: {
      object(SuggestedDocumentStyle)
    },
    ...
  },
  "namedStyles": {
    object(NamedStyles)
  },
  "suggestedNamedStylesChanges": {
    string: {
      object(SuggestedNamedStyles)
    },
    ...
  },
  "lists": {
    string: {
      object(List)
    },
    ...
  },
  "namedRanges": {
    string: {
      object(NamedRanges)
    },
    ...
  },
  "revisionId": string,
  "suggestionsViewMode": enum(SuggestionsViewMode),
  "inlineObjects": {
    string: {
      object(InlineObject)
    },
    ...
  },
  "positionedObjects": {
    string: {
      object(PositionedObject)
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

The fields `headers` and `footers` stand for the headers and footers in the document, keyed by header ID and footer ID respectively.

Comment: After using the `documents.create` request, the resulting Document resource does not actually contain the `headers` field to retrieve the `headerId`